# PHP 5.6 Curl Unusual Behavior

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

In a middle of a project I was trying to download some images with PHP.

I'm using the simple html dom.

Here the example:

```
function scaper_allegati_fo($url,$id_imm)
{   
    $html_fo_p=file_get_html($url);
    $pagine = $html_fo_p->find('span[class=sTotAlleg]',0)->plaintext;
    $goodUrl = str_replace('&pos=1', '', $url);
    for($i = 1; $i < $pagine; $i++) 
    {
        $newurl = $goodUrl."&pos=".$i;
        $html_fo=file_get_html($newurl);
        $img_link = $html_fo->find('img[class=imgBckWait]',0)->src;
        $download = file_get_contents("$img_link");
        $estensione = ".jpg";
        $nome_tmp = $id_imm."_FO_";
        $random = random_str(10);
        $nome = $nome_tmp.$random;
        file_put_contents('/var/www/html/allegati/'.$nome.$estensione, $download);
    }
```

Here the problem:

The link that I'm trying to download is like this:

```
https://www.astegiudiziarie.it/CA/browsefile.aspx?idl=74CRZD366266224&nf=Foto-AO-F-2-2016-2.jpg&nfcod=6d2ecb3f5615ee1024672dc8b6a80e52&s=FO
```

The file which get downloaded is only 26 bytes and contains a string with an error from the website which is equivalent to "decode error".
This happens when the URL is cut from its argument.

I try to use curl, a curl class already made (https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class) and the function copy.

Every time is like I get the link "cut" of the argument that come with.

Example: Instead of `https://www.astegiudiziarie.it/CA/browsefile.aspx?idl=74CRZD366266224&nf=Foto-AO-F-2-2016-2.jpg&nfcod=6d2ecb3f5615ee1024672dc8b6a80e52&s=FO`

you go on

```
https://www.astegiudiziarie.it/CA/browsefile.aspx?idl=74CRZD366266224&nf=Foto-AO-F-2-2016-2.jpg
```

If I try to use the file_get_contents manually, with just the link, it works!

I try to echo the link I was scraping and they come perfectly well.
I try to echo the link with `<img src="$img_link" />` and the pictures show up.

But every time I try to download with my code I get an empty file.

Is it because somewhere the $img_link get clean from its arguments?

Anyone have a clue on what I can try about this?

Comment: _“This happens when the url is cut from his argument”_ - no clue what you are trying to say here.

Comment: When for example instead of going on https://www.astegiudiziarie.it/CA/browsefile.aspx?idl=74CRZD366266224&nf=Foto-AO-F-2-2016-2.jpg&nfcod=6d2ecb3f5615ee1024672dc8b6a80e52&s=FO you remove the &nfcod

Comment: Well then don’t remove it ...? You don’t really expect that you can change or remove parts of URLs willy-nilly, and still get the same result?

Comment: I express wrongly, i dont wanna remove any part of the url. The behavior that i saw, is that the file that i got downloaded contain a string with the error "decode error". That happens when you cut the url. So i suspect that somewhere the url get somehow cut.

Comment: Well if it works with file_get_contents, but not with that cURL wrapper class you are using there - then I would expect the problem to be with the latter.

Comment: I try to use curl and file_get_contects with the link directly in the code and it work but when i instead make the function downloading it i get the right number of file with all with inside the string "decode error" wich occur when you go on one if those link cutting them. My suspect is that like i said before somewhere those link get cut, just cant find where

Comment: And I rather suspect that the URLs you are reading from that document are not what you expect to begin with ... so verify that first of all.

Comment: Yes was what i was thinking at begi. So i echo them at screen, perfect. Echo them with some html like <img src"$img_link" />, working all img show up. The moment i try to download them nothing

Comment: They might check the request for other stuff, such as cookies or a specific user-agent. (Such measures are usually applied by sites that _don’t want_ you to do what you are trying to do …)

Comment: Any tips where i should investigate or try to solve it?